# Remove all the words from a list of lists which occur in a given set

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to do three simple steps efficiently in Python.

I have a list of lists (of strings). Let us call it `L`.

> 1. I want to flatten the list of lists to a single list LL. (I know how to do this efficiently)
> 2. Construct the set of words with frequency 1 from the list LL of step 1. Let us call this set S. (I also know how to do this
>      efficiently)
> 3. Remove all the words from the list of lists L which occur in S.

If you can suggest an efficient way of doing step 3, that will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a simple `list comprehension` for the 3rd step:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> L=[['a','b'],['foo','bar'],['spam','eggs'],['b','c'],['spam','bar']]
>>> S=Counter(chain(*L))
>>> S
Counter({'b': 2, 'bar': 2, 'spam': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'eggs': 1, 'foo': 1})

>>> [[y for y in x if S[y]!=1] for x in L]
[['b'], ['bar'], ['spam'], ['b'], ['spam', 'bar']]
```

if you've a set `R`:

```
>>> L=[['a','b'],['foo','bar'],['spam','eggs'],['b','c'],['spam','bar']]
>>> R={'a','foo'}
>>> [[y for y in x if y not in R] for x in L]
[['b'], ['bar'], ['spam', 'eggs'], ['b', 'c'], ['spam', 'bar']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ashwini. Another related question is how to go about step 3 if the set S is already given. Please let me know. Best regards,

Comment: I'll definitely accept the answer. Please let me know how to do that. Also kindly answer the "related question". It will be a great help. Best regards,

Comment: @Dibyendu where's the related question?

Comment: Thanks, Ashwini. Suppose I have a given set R (R is already constructed) and I want to remove all the words from the list of lists L which occur in R. How do I do that efficiently? Best regards,

Comment: I think the list comprehension is efficient as well as simple:
`[[y for y in x if y not in R] for x in L]`

Comment: one more question: If R is small but L is very large, is there any other faster solution? Best regards,

Comment: @Dibyendu you can use `set difference` : `[list(set(x)-R) for x in L]
`, but you may loose the order of elements in sublists this way.

Comment: @Dibyendu I just timed but solutions using simple LC and using set difference, and it turns out that first approach was faster as creation of set has it's own overhead.

Comment: Thanks alot, Ashiwini. I am posting another similar question. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
import operator

LL = reduce(operator.add, L)
counted_L = collections.Counter(LL)
def filter_singles(sublist):
  return [value for value in sublist if counted_L[value] != 1]
no_single_freq_L = [filter_singles(sublist) for sublist in L]
```

Comment: Double check the post. `LL` is the flatted version. By calling `Counter(L)` we actually get some kind of equivalent to `LL` with counts for each value.

Comment: No you don't , you need to flatten the list first.

Comment: If `L` is a list of lists, then `Counter(L)` won't work anyway; lists aren't hashable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bossylobster. Another related question is how to go about step 3 if the set S is already given. Please let me know. Best regards,

Comment: Just replace `counted_L[value] != 1` by `value not in S`, assuming `S` is an instance of `set` in Python. BTW If you liked my answer you should've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned creating a set in your step 2.  The built-in type [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) can make your step 3 really easy to read and understand.

```
# if you are already working with sets:
LL - S

# or convert to sets
set(LL) - set(S)
```

Quick example

```
>>> all_ten = set(range(0,10))
>>> evens = set(range(0,10,2))
>>> odds = all_ten - evens
>>> odds
set([0, 8, 2, 4, 6,])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Istruble. Another related question is how to go about step 3 if the set S is already given. Please let me know. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> #Tools Needed
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> #Just for this example
>>> import keyword
>>> import random
>>> #Now create your example data
>>> L = [random.sample(keyword.kwlist,5) for _ in xrange(5)]
>>> #Flatten the List (Step 1)
>>> LL = itertools.chain(*L)
>>> #Create Word Freq (Step 2)
>>> freq = collections.Counter(LL)
>>> #Remove all words with unit frequency (Step 3)
>>> LL = itertools.takewhile(lambda e:freq[e] > 1,freq)
>>> #Display Your result
>>> list(LL)
['and']
>>> L
[['in', 'del', 'if', 'while', 'print'], ['exec', 'try', 'for', 'if', 'finally'], ['and', 'for', 'if', 'print', 'lambda'], ['as', 'for', 'or', 'return', 'else'], ['and', 'global', 'or', 'while', 'lambda']]
>>>
```